# TimerManager.SetTimer - no viable function - Function is missing const qualifier

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5, unreal-development-kit, unreal

I am trying to Toggle a light after a specified Delay in Unreal 5.X. This is my approach:

```
void AC_LightSwitch_CodeOnly::ToggleLightAfterDelay(int32 DelayInMilliseconds) const
{
    FTimerHandle Timer;
    FTimerDelegate const& Delegate = FTimerDelegate::CreateLambda([]
    {
        UC_Logger::Warn("Light Switch Async fired UwU");
    });
    const UWorld* World = GetWorld();
    const FTimerManager& TimerManager = World->GetTimerManager();
    float Delay = DelayInMilliseconds / 1000.0F;
>>  TimerManager.SetTimer(Timer, Delegate, Delay, false, -1.f); // No viable function
    // Function is missing const qualifier
}
```

At the marked line I receive an compiler error telling me there is no matching overload... but I just cant understand ...

---

The overload im trying to use is:

```
inline void SetTimer(FTimerHandle& InOutHandle, FTimerDelegate const& InDelegate, float InRate, bool InbLoop, float InFirstDelay = -1)
```

I also tried removing the `const` from the `Delegate` tried around a lot, but I just can't get an idea why it's telling me that. Delegate is a const.

---

Here's the tooltip from Rider for the issue: [Tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37gpx.png)

And for better code readablilty a screenshot of this section: [Colored Codeblock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEGQ9.png)

Comment: `TimerManager` is const because `ToggleLightAfterDelay()` is const, `SetTimer()` is not const. Remove `const` after `ToggleLightAfterDelay()`.

Comment: `TimeManager` is const because `const FTimerManager& TimerManager = World->GetTimerManager();` has `const` on the reference.  Change that to `FTimerManager& TimerManager = World->GetTimerManager();`.

Comment: So now you have two options on what is the design problem. Because the problem is rather in the design, and not necessarily in the coding. You might want to ask yourself why a function called `ToggleLight` is `const`, because it sure sounds like something is going to change.

Comment: Thank you for your answers guys :) I didnt quiet understood how a `const` variable that holds a class could possible influence the lookup for a matching overload.. :/ The tooltip kinda lead me the wrong way by telling me a `const` is *missing*.. 

And to your answer @BoP , I added const because Rider recommended me to. I thought adding const sounds right because the method doesn't change any of it's parameters.  Thanks to you I understand what the const behind a method means :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to you guys I found the root of my error.
Just like you said I could not find a viable function because `FTimeManager` had a `const` qualifier.

I did not quiet understand the relation why the const of a variable influences the way I find overloads. :)

Removed it and now it works, here's the new code:

```
void AC_LightSwitch_CodeOnly::ToggleLightAfterDelay(const int32 DelayInMilliseconds) const
{
    FTimerHandle Timer;
    const FTimerDelegate &Delegate = FTimerDelegate::CreateLambda([]
    {
        UC_Logger::Warn("Light Switch Async fired UwU");
    });

    const UWorld* World = GetWorld();
    FTimerManager& TimerManager = World->GetTimerManager();
    const float& Delay = DelayInMilliseconds / 1000.0F;
    TimerManager.SetTimer(Timer, Delegate, Delay, false);
}
```

Thank you all and have a great day!